# What is the difference between screen shot and screenshot, where do we use screen shot and screenshot

Tags: american-english, vocabulary, business-language

What is the difference between screen shot and screenshot, where do we use screen shot and screenshot. Are they used interchangeably?

Comment: The preferred term is *screenshot*, “screen shot” is hardly ever used (maybe never). Here is [what the literature says](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=screenshot%2C+screen+shot&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cscreenshot%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cscreen%20shot%3B%2Cc0). Also there is no difference in meaning; they are interchangeable.